# tmux kill many windows at once

Tags: unix, tmux

I have a ton of windows open on my tmux session and I want to kill 75% of them. Is there a way to kill multiple windows at once instead of going to each window and killing it individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `tmux` supports this internally, but you can script it.

First create a test session to work on:

```
tmux new -s test
repeat 9;        do tmux new-window -t test; done    # in zsh
for i in {1..9}; do tmux new-window -t test; done    # in bash
```

And now for the window killing:

```
# number of windows in test session
nwin=$(tmux list-windows -t test | wc -l)

# number of windows to kill
nkill=$(echo "$nwin * .75" | bc -l | cut -d. -f1)

tmux list-windows -t test | cut -d: -f1 | head -n$nkill \
| while read; do
    tmux kill-window -t test:$REPLY
  done
```

This is a fairly flexible approach, and you should be able to `grep -v` any windows you want to keep, or conversely `grep` the ones you want to kill.

Comment: More generally, if there is a distinct set of windows to kill, `for win in window1 window7 window9; do tmux kill-window -t $win; done`. And I wish `bash` had a `repeat` construct like `zsh`.

Comment: Forgot that `bash` doesn't support `repeat`, will add `bash` alternative.

Comment: I use in my .tmux.conf: `bind X command-prompt -p "Windows to kill:" 'run-shell "for w in $(tmux display-message -p \"%%\"); do tmux kill-window -t \$w; done;"'`. Add the numbers of windows as space separated values, e.g., hit <PREFIX>X -> "Windows to kill: 3 5 8 15", to kill windows 3 5 8 and 15. Don't turn on `renumber-windows` though ;)

Comment: In case anyone wanted to know, I improved the command to kill multiple windows, such that it also works with renumber-windows on: `bind C-x command-prompt -p 'Windows to kill:' 'run-shell "for w in \$(echo %% | sort -n -r); do tmux kill-window -t \$w; done;"'`. Again, provide window numbers (#I), space separated.

Comment: I am having following error message `head: option requires an argument -- 'n'` is it normal?

Comment: @alper: no, it means the `$nkill` variable is empty

Comment: `tmux list-windows -t goo1 | cut -d: -f1` returns multiple int values with new line , I get lost how can I pipe them into while. Shouldn't we use `xargs`?

Comment: @PKul: post this as a new question